# Vector overlay intersection ERROR

Tags: qgis

My base 2 layers are:
"cleaned 1703"(road network)
"centroids 1703" (points layer)

I have a road network and I need to identify from a points layer what are the shortest path to an specific point. For that, I am using the plugin: **Shortest path (layer to point)**. It gives me as result a layer that contains many paths that I am calling "fastest path 090322/path1703".
[image]
After that, I need to find: what features from road network are content in each shortest path. For that, I am using the plugin: **Vector overlay Intersection**
[image]
When I get the new layer "intersection" and see the features, I do not get complete information. There are some features from the road networks that are included in the shortest paths, but my new layer is not considering.
For example, It is not giving me as a result these features in the attribute fid: 2760, 51, 230 from the "cleaned 1703"(road network).

[image: circuled on red fid 2760 that does not appear in layer vector overlay intersection and it is in the short path on purple]

Files in this link
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jwNPch_pf_3QSRaZrQie957mW-Gc8wDY

Comment: Can you share your data? Difficult to say what's going on

Comment: Sorry for the delay. 
Instead of Join by location I am using VECTOR OVER- Intersection that suits better my purpose, but still INCOMPLETE features. 
Layers: centroids 1703 (points layer), cleaned 1703(road network), path1703(points layer to specific point through road network) here is my data: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jwNPch_pf_3QSRaZrQie957mW-Gc8wDY?usp=sharing

Please, let me know if I was enough clear, too.

Comment: Examples of features not showed when "intersect" layers 'cleaned 1703' and 'path1703' are: 2760, 51, 230

Comment: @Babel please if you can help me comments up

Comment: Sorry, your question is very confusing, I do not understand what you're doing. I advice you editing your question and posting the link to the data there and describe in a more understandable way what you do and what problem you encounter.

Comment: @Babel thank you for your answer, hopefully now my edited is more clear

Comment: I see what you mean. However, I'm not sure why you want to get the intersection? What you want to do seems just to get a copy of the fastest path layer - this does not seem to make sense to me. By the way: you're not using any plugings, you're using QGIS native tools.

Comment: @Babel Thanks for the corrections. When I use the fastest path layer it just shows me fast paths and does not include any attribute of my road network detail. What I need is the features of my road network that are included in each fast path.

Answer (score 1):

Create a (small) buffer of someting like 10 m around the network layer. The buffer should contain the initial attributes.

Than use [Join attributes by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location) from `Menu Processing > Toolbox`. This checks which lines of the fastest path are inside the buffer and takes the attributes from there. Check below for correct settings. Creating a spatial index before running the tool could be a good idea.

Use the following settings:

- `Base layer` = fastest path
- `Join layer` = buffer
- `Geometric prediacte` = intersects (disable all others)
- `Join type`: set to `take attributes of the first matching feature only (one-to-one)`

Comment: I did what you suggested but it didn't work, new layer was just including "road network" features but not related with past path.

Comment: Be sure to include the right layer in the dialog window and check if the buffer layer includes the initial attributes.